# editable info window not working in android, but works in reg browser

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-maps-api-3

the editable info window content works in a regular (pc) browser, but
does not work in android webview in my app.  If i browse to my page
with my phones browser, only the submit button works (just barely, the
behavior is odd/slow), but i cannot get to the other editable content
(edittext, select options).

my js sensors set to true, have a java to javascript bridge.  I am
using webview to view my v3 map, and on click of any marker my
infowindow content shows, but cannot edit/submit the infowindow
content like I can in regular browser.

What am I missing?  Thought I might be able to initially ask without
posting code, please let me know if anyone has any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your browser it's not supporting Javascript?
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Have a look:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html